# Set props as state in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here i want to set props to state in child component.
I have a table that fill with ajax request. btw I'm using **[antd](http://ant.design/)** library.
there is an Edit button on my table that should open a modal that contains a form.

**Parent Component**

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import API from '../../Helpers/Api'
import {Table, Divider, Tag, message, Popconfirm, Icon} from 'antd';
import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  Col,
  Row
} from 'reactstrap';
import EditCountry from './EditCountry'


var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
let config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
}


class ListCountry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.columns = [
      {
        title: 'نام کشور‌',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        // render: text => <a href="javascript:;">{text}</a>,
      },
      {
        title: 'وضعیت',
        dataIndex: 'isForeign',
        key: 'isForeign',
        render: isForeign => (
          <div>
            <Tag color={isForeign ? 'blue' : 'purple'}>
              {isForeign ? 'کشور خارجی است' : 'کشور خارجی نیست'}
            </Tag>

          </div>
        ),
      },
      {
        title: '',
        dataIndex: '',
        key: 'x',
        render: (text, record) =>
          this.state.countries.length >= 1 ? (
            <span>
               <a onClick={() => this.handleEdit(record.key)}>ویرایش کشور</a>
               <Divider type="vertical" />
               <Popconfirm
                 icon={<Icon type="question-circle-o" style={{ color: 'red' }} />}
                 title="آیا از حذف این کشور مطمئن هستید؟"
                 onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}
                 okText="حذف"
                 cancelText="لغو"
               >
                 <a>حذف کشور</a>
              </Popconfirm>
            </span>

          ) : null,
      },
    ];
    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      openModal: false,
      rowId:''
    }
  }

  getCountries = e => {
    var self = this;
    axios.get( API + '/country',
      config
    )
      .then(function (response) {

        const results= response.data.map(row => ({
          key: row._id, // I added this line
          name: row.name,
          isForeign: row.isForeign,
          Id: row._id,
        }))
        self.setState({ countries : results });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
      this.getCountries();
  }

  handleDelete = id => {
    var self = this;
    axios.delete( API + `/country/${id}`,
      config
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        const countries = [...self.state.countries];
        self.setState({ countries: countries.filter(item => item.key !== id) });
        message.success('عملیات حذف با موفقیت انجام شد.')
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleEdit = id => {
    this.setState({
      rowId: id,
      openModal: !this.state.openModal
    })
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <div className="animated fadeIn">
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col xs="12" md="12">
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <strong>لیست کشورها</strong>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
          <Table className="rtl text-right" columns={this.columns} dataSource={this.state.countries}/>
          <EditCountry open={ this.state.openModal } handleEdit= {this.handleEdit} rowId={ this.state.rowId } />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

export default ListCountry;

**Child Component**

```
    class EditCountry extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          id : this.props.rowId
        };
      }

      handleCancel = () => {
          this.props.handleEdit();
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Modal
              title="Basic Modal"
            >
// form
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

so as you see i'm setting props as state but the `id` is empty, am i missing something ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the parent component, where rowId is saved?

Comment: yes sure, updated my question

Comment: Post the entire component.

Comment: In your child component, use props.rowId instead.

Comment: no luck, it's empty because at first rowId is empty but after ajax request i've set to rowId

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow for rowID is like this:

1. You set the initial state of the parent to be rowId = ""
2. You pass that to the child component and it gets saved in the child state
3. You call this.props.handleEdit like this: `this.props.handleEdit();`
4. You update your state with rowId: id in handleEdit
5. The parent rowId will not copied to the child state id because it is only set in the component constructor.

At the beginning, rowId is "", because that is the default in your state of the parent => This will be the id of the child.

The problem is, that you call `this.props.handleEdit` without an id. This will set your rowId to be undefined in the parent.

You have to set the rowId somewhere in your code, for example in your child component like this:

```
 this.props.handleEdit(myID); or this.props.handleEdit(this.state.id);
```

This will set the id and rowID will be defined to whatever you pass to handleEdit.

But this will not update your id in your state within your child component, since the constructor will not be called again after the parent state updates.

To update the child state, you will have to listen to rowId changes with componentDidUpdate or use this.props.rowId  directly from the parent component.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.rowId!== prevProps.rowId) {
    this.setState({id: this.props.rowId});
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any life cycle method that will trigger right after the child component get called ?

Comment: What do you mean with get called? There is componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

Comment: when I hit edit button on table, i will set the rowId and show modal, maybe I can set rowId props to child state after that.

Comment: Yes you can update your id from the modal with setState. Then you have to pass that to the this.props.handleEdit function. This will update the parent rowId state.

Comment: That's my question acutally. i want to set rowId as state in my child component, but i can't do it.

Comment: You have to use [didUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Read that and you will be able to set your state in your child component. I updated my answer.

Comment: jup, that's working now, thanks a million for your time